# как разместить скрол поверх контента, а не сбоку?

Tags: html, css

как разместить скрол поверх контента, а не сбоку?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0
    }

    .scrollable-container {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    .content {
        height: 100px;
        background-color: aqua;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div class="scrollable-container">
    <div class="scrollable-content">
        <div class="content">
            блок
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            блок
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Делать кастомный скролл бар.

Comment: Выбирай - https://www.cssscript.com/best-custom-scrollbar-javascript-libraries/

Comment: @ksa а есть ли простейнький вариант без библиотек? css + html

Comment: В браузеры не особо пекутся на счет лифтов... Это сам народ желает поизголяться на эту тему.